# Tying values to keys in a dictionary and then printing

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, storing-data

This is a smaller portion of the main code I have been writing. Depending on user selection they can add player informationa and then print the information from the dictionary player roster. I want to store the information and then print in this format but I havent been able to figure out how to do this.
                    Name ****
                    Phone Number ****
                    Jersey Number ****
Im new to dictionaries but I have spent hours reading and searching over the past couple of days about dictionaries and have tried several different ways to do this but failed. I have gotten the closest the way I have it setup now but it still doesnt work right. I feel like I am storing the information incorrectly into the dictionary for starters, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
player_roster = {}
def display_roster(self):                         #Print Roster
    if len(player_roster) != 0:
        for x in player_roster.keys():
            print('Name:', x, 'Phone Number:', player_roster[x])
    else:                                          #Print No One on Roster
        len(player_roster) == []
        print('No names have been entered:')

def add_player(self,):                              #Enter Members Name
    name = input('Enter New Players Name:')
    phone_number = input('Enter Players Phone Number:')
    jersey_number = int(input('Enter Players Jersey Number'))
    player_roster[name] = phone_number, 'Jersey Number', jersey_number
#If I input Toby as Name 444-444 as Phone Number and 3 as Jersey number it outputs like this
Name: Toby Phone Number: ('444-4444', 'Jersey Number', 3)
# I would like it to output like 
                                 Name: Toby
                                 Phone Number: 444-4444
                                 Jersey Number: 3
```

Comment: In your print function, add '\n' between each key-value pair

Answer (score 1):

There are some things i would change in your code but to keep this close to what you asked for take a look at this:

```
def display_roster():
    if len(player_roster) != 0:
        for x in player_roster.keys():
            print('Name:', x)
            print('Phone Number:', player_roster[x][0])
            print('Jersey Number:', player_roster[x][1])
    else:
        print('Roster is empty.')
    return


player_roster = {}
def add_player():
    name = input('Enter New Players Name:\t')
    phone_number = input('Enter Players Phone Number:\t')
    jersey_number = int(input('Enter Players Jersey Number:\t'))
    player_roster[name] = [phone_number, jersey_number]
    return

add_player()
display_roster()

# PRINTS:
#Name: Toby
#Phone Number: 444-4444
#Jersey Number: 3
```

Printing in multiple lines gives you the result you want. As stated in the comments this can also be done with a single `print()` statement but i do not think compact code makes much difference to you yet.

Further, this `len(self.player_roster) == []` line  does not make sense. This is as good as simply writing `True` in a line. The "emptiness" of the team is checked by the `else:`.

Finally, i would slightly change the way players are stored in the "Roster" dictionary and have it like this: `{"Toby": ['444-4444', 3], ...}`

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much there. The below modification would allow you to print as you need (and is slightly more readable):

```
class PlayerDictionary():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    player_roster = {}
    def display_roster(self):                         #Print Roster
        if len(self.player_roster) != 0:
            for key, value in self.player_roster.iteritems():
                print(str(key) + ": " + str(value))
        else:                                          #Print No One on Roster
            len(self.player_roster) == []
            print('No names have been entered:')

    def add_player(self,):
        self.player_roster['Name'] = input('Enter New Players Name:')
        self.player_roster['Phone Number'] = input('Enter Players Phone Number:')
        self.player_roster['Jersey Number'] = int(input('Enter Players Jersey Number'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    player = PlayerDictionary()
    player.add_player()
    player.display_roster()
```

A slightly more maintainable solution would be to create a class for Player. Set the properties on the object and overload the **str** function e.g.

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__name = ""
        self.__phone_number = ""
        self.__jersey_number = ""

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @property
    def phone_number(self):
        return self.__phone_number

    @property
    def jersey_number(self):
        return self.__jersey_number

    @name.setter
    def name(self, val):
        self.__name = val

    @phone_number.setter
    def phone_number(self, val):
        self.__phone_number = val

    @jersey_number.setter
    def jersey_number(self, val):
        self.__jersey_number = val

    def __str__(self):
        return ("Name: %s\nPhone Number: %s\nJersey Number: %s" % (str(self.__name), str(self.__phone_number), str(self.__jersey_number)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    player = Player()
    player.name = input('Enter New Players Name:')
    player.phone_number = input('Enter Players Phone Number:')
    player.jersey_number = int(input('Enter Players Jersey Number'))
    print(player)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose that you replace the print statement to this:

```
print(" Name: %s \n Phone Number: %s \n Jersey Number: %d") % player_roster[x]
```